# Passing Daterangepicker parameter to JQuery DataTable With Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatable, daterangepicker

I have created a Table using the Jquery Datatable with Ajax and it works great, I have created a daterangepicker to filtering datatable.

```js
<link href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/date.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() 
  {
   var startdate = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
   var enddate = moment();
   function cb(startdate, enddate) {
    $('#reservation span').html(startdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ~ ' + enddate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
   }
   $('#reservation').daterangepicker({
    start: startdate,
    end: enddate,
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
   }, cb);
   cb(startdate, enddate);
  });
 </script>
  

 <script src="./js/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
   // DataTable
    $('#Show-Tables').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "ajax": {
     "url": "dt-json-data.php",
     "type": "POST",
     "dataSrc": "records"
    },
    "columns": [
     { "data": "Tanggal" },
     { "data": "CustomerNo" },
     { "data": "CustomerName" },
     { "data": "Branch" },
     { "data": "Tot_Menit" },
     { "data": "Tot_call" }
    ],
    "autoWidth": true
   });
  });
 </script>



<?php
//Here is my code for dt-json-data.php file :
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "*****";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
 0 => 'Tanggal',
 1 => 'CustomerNo',
 2 => 'CustomerName',
 3 => 'Branch',
 4 => 'Tot_Menit',
 5 => 'Tot_call'
);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT * ";  //intensionaly * to fetch all columns
$sql.=" FROM Tot_cdr_all";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


$sql = "Select Tanggal,CustomerNo,CustomerName,Branch,sum(Tot_Menit) as Tot_Menit,sum(Tot_call) as Tot_call From Tot_cdr_all WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
 $sql.=" AND DATE_FORMAT(Tanggal,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('%".$requestData['search']['value']."%','%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('%".$requestData['search']['value']."%','%Y-%m-%d') ";
 $sql.=" OR ( UPPER(CustomerName) like UPPER('%".$requestData['search']['value']."%') OR UPPER(Branch) like UPPER('%".$requestData['search']['value']."%') OR UPPER(CustomerNo) like UPPER('%".$requestData['search']['value']."%') ) ";
}
$sql.=" GROUP BY 1,2,3,4";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
$sql.=" ORDER BY 1,3 LIMIT ".(empty($requestData['start']) ? 0 : $requestData['start']).", ".$requestData['length']."   ";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$totalFiltered = $totalData; // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {  // preparing an array
 $nestedData=array(); 

 foreach($row as $index=>$value) {
  $nestedData[$index] = $value;
 }

 $data[] = $nestedData;
}

$json_data = array(
   "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
   "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
   "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
   "records"         => $data   // total data array
   );
//print_r($data);

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="#"  method="post" name="niceform" class="form-horizontal">
<div id="daterange" class="pull-left" style="margin-left: 15px">
    <div id="reservation" class="input-prepend" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
     <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 15px">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Ok" class="btn btn-facebook" />
   </div>
</form>

   <div class="box-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="display" id="Show-Tables" width="100%">
      <thead>
       <tr align="center">
        <th><center>Tanggal</center></th>
        <th><center>Customer No.</center></th>
        <th><center>Customer Name</center></th>
        <th><center>Branch</center></th>
        <th><center>Total Menit</center></th>
        <th><center>Total Call</center></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i passing daterangepicker value to filter my datatables?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your date range stuff in my environment but made one minor change.
I added a data range change event to force datatables to run ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var startdate = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
        var enddate = moment();
        function cb(startdate, enddate) {
            $('#reservation span').html(startdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ~ ' + enddate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

This cb function is a callback function so it was what I think was causing your issue.  There was no way to guarantee the timing between its first call and the datatable ajax call.

Since this function is called every time the dates are changed, I got rid of the event handler and used this to trigger the datatable ajax call.

```
                         $('#example').DataTable().draw();
        }
        $('#reservation').daterangepicker({
            start: startdate,
            end: enddate,
            ranges: {
               'Today': [moment(), moment()],
               'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
               'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
               'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
               'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
               'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb)
```

As stated above, I removed the event handler that I initially put here.

```
        cb(startdate, enddate);

    });
</script>
```

But because we want to pass the dates even when other things, such as text entered in the search box, I don't actually pass the dates in that event handler. I get the dates in the datatable ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        // DataTable
        $('#Show-Tables').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
```

I added defer loading. This means the data table is created but the first call to get data is delayed until it is triggered by some other action. This gives the date picker time to be created before the data is fetched.

```
                            "deferLoading":0,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "ajax": {
                "url": "dt-json-data.php",
                "type": "POST",
                ////  Addded section to get the dates based on daterangepicker documentation
                data: function (dtParms) {
                    var start = $('#reservation').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format();
                    var end = $('#reservation').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format();
                    // I put the dates in the search object but you can put it where you want inside the object.
                    dtParms.search.startDate = start;
                    dtParms.search.endData = end;
                    return dtParms;
                },
                "dataSrc": "records"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Tanggal" },
                { "data": "CustomerNo" },
                { "data": "CustomerName" },
                { "data": "Branch" },
                { "data": "Tot_Menit" },
                { "data": "Tot_call" }
            ],
            "autoWidth": true
        });
    });
</script>I tested this against my environment so make sure I did not make misstates to make it fit yours.
```

Comment: Hi Bindrid, your suggestion was not working yet on my script. There are some error while i tried your suggestion (i was captured it for you, please take a look).

Comment: its probably a timing issue.   I think that data tables is trying to access the date range object before its done being built